# Text color in wpf listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, textcolor

I have an issue with an listview element in my WPF-application.
I added a listview to my usercontrol (Foreground="Black") and set bindings.
If I now add items to this listview the text in each row seems to be not visible - but I want to be the text color to be e.g. black.

This is my xaml for the listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewPackResults_Bulk" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="312" Margin="64,379,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1300" BorderThickness="1" Background="{x:Null}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Process" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PackTransaction}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Return Code" Width="112" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReturnCode}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Product Code" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductCode}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Batch ID" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BatchID}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Batch Expiry" Width="115" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BatchExpiry}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Serial number" Width="122" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PackSerialnumber}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Pack Status" Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PackStatus}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Reason" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReasonString}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Return Description" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReturnDescription}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I'm adding items by clicking on a button:

```
    public List<Pack> requestItems = new List<Pack>();
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        requestItems.Add(new Pack() { PackTransaction = ComboBoxTransaction_Bulk.SelectedValue.ToString(), ProductCode = TextBox_ProductCode_Bulk.Text, BatchID = TextBoxBatchID_Bulk.Text, BatchExpiry = TextBoxBatchExpiry_Bulk.Text, PackSerialnumber = TextBoxSerialNumber_Bulk.Text});
        ListViewBulkRequests_Bulk.ItemsSource = requestItems;
        ICollectionView view_requests = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(requestItems);
        view_requests.Refresh();
    }
```

Pack is my own class with the corresponding variables you can see above (e.g. PackTransaction). I'm gettin the values from Textboxes and a Combobox. In debugging mode I can see, that the items are in the listview, but my application looks like this:
[listview with "no" text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/753Lz.jpg)

Can someone help me? Please be nice to me - I'm no developer at all. :-(

Comment: Try `TextElement.Foreground=Black` in your listview. Might help.

Comment: Please excuse me, but I'm not that good in programming. Could you please give me a code-example? :-)

Comment: this is for sure not an issue with the Foreground color..the default is always black! I tried your code with my own object and i can see the data..have you applied any other style to the listview? Also one small typo/error in your code - ListViewBulkRequests_Bulk whose itemsource you're setting is not the same as ListViewPackResults_Bulk listview.

Comment: Thank you very much - the comment that there is a typo/error in my code helped to solve it. In my question-post I added the wrong listview. And while taking a look at the correct list view I recognized that the binding was incorrect. It was e.g. <GridViewColumn Header="Process" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PackTransaction_Request}"/> instead of <GridViewColumn Header="Process" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PackTransaction}"/>. THANK YOU!